# What problem does a reinitializable iterator solve?

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

From the [tf.data documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator):

> A reinitializable iterator can be initialized from multiple different
>   Dataset objects. For example, you might have a training input pipeline
>   that uses random perturbations to the input images to improve
>   generalization, and a validation input pipeline that evaluates
>   predictions on unmodified data. These pipelines will typically use
>   different Dataset objects that have the same structure (i.e. the same
>   types and compatible shapes for each component).

the following example was given:

```
# Define training and validation datasets with the same structure.
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100).map(
    lambda x: x + tf.random_uniform([], -10, 10, tf.int64))
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(50)

# A reinitializable iterator is defined by its structure. We could use the
# `output_types` and `output_shapes` properties of either `training_dataset`
# or `validation_dataset` here, because they are compatible.
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(training_dataset.output_types,
                                           training_dataset.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()

training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(training_dataset)
validation_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(validation_dataset)

# Run 20 epochs in which the training dataset is traversed, followed by the
# validation dataset.
for _ in range(20):
  # Initialize an iterator over the training dataset.
  sess.run(training_init_op)
  for _ in range(100):
    sess.run(next_element)

  # Initialize an iterator over the validation dataset.
  sess.run(validation_init_op)
  for _ in range(50):
    sess.run(next_element)
```

It is unclear what the benefit of this complexity is.
Why not simply create 2 different iterators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original motivation for reinitializable iterators was as follows:

1. The user's input data is in two or more `tf.data.Dataset` objects with the same structure but different pipeline definitions.

   For example, you might have a training data pipeline with augmentations in a `Dataset.map()`, and an evaluation data pipeline that produced raw examples, but they would both produce batches with the same structure (in terms of the number of tensors, their element types, shapes, etc.).
2. The user would define a single training graph that took input from a `tf.data.Iterator`, created using `Iterator.from_structure()`.
3. The user could then switch between the different input data sources by **reinitializing** the iterator from one of the datasets.

In hindsight, reinitializable iterators have turned out to be quite hard to use for their intended purpose. In TensorFlow 2.0 (or 1.x with eager execution enabled), it is much easier to create iterators over different datasets using idiomatic Python `for` loops and high-level training APIs:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()

model = ...  # A `tf.keras.Model`, or some other class exposing `fit()` and `evaluate()` methods.

train_data = ...  # A `tf.data.Dataset`.
eval_data = ...   # A `tf.data.Dataset`.

for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
  model.fit(train_data, ...)

  # Evaluate every 5 epochs.
  if i % 5 == 0: 
    model.evaluate(eval_data, ...)
```